# Why opacity has not set in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I have done program to create pop up div block.
In that I create div block with four input tags.I append this with a body tag.
Then I try to make opacity view for whold body other than this div tag.

So I tried this

```
document.body.style="opacity:0.3";
document.getElementById("div_block").style="opacity:1";
```

opacity for div_block set correctly it shows value of opacity is 1.
But in web page the opacity is affect the div_block also.
How to avoid that ????

Comment: `.style.cssText="opacity:0.3"` or `.style.opacity="0.3"`

Comment: Please show your ("*[mcve]*') code. Incidentally it sounds, from your description, that you're adding another`<body>` element to the page, if you are *don't*, there can be only one body element per document. Also: opacity is inherited, a child cannot be more opaque than its ancestors.

Comment: As mentioned by Jaromanda, `style` is an object, not a string.

Comment: It is large program. In body tag I had header,navigation and another one div tag which covered remaining width and height.

Comment: yes it is an object I agree with that.document. getElementById("div_block").style="display:block"  -it is working correctly . so that I used like that

Answer (score 0):

Since your popups are children of `body` they will be affected by its opacity.

To avoid this, typically you will place a `div` with 100% width and 100% height above everything *but* your popup, and give it a partially transparent background (eg. `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)`).

Answer (score 0):

Because your syntax is wrong:

```
document.body.style.opacity='0.3';
document.getElementById("div_block").style.opacity='0.3';
```

Comment: After setting the opacity I checked the value of opacity of tags by getPropertyValue function . It return the value which i has set. so If the syntax is wrong then how getPropertyValue function return a opacity value 1 for div_block.

Answer (score 0):

This happens since the `div_block` element is a descendant of the `body` element, and **IS** part of the view layer that is affected by the `opacity:0.3;` declaration.

The opacity value of the `body` is actually the "base line" for computing the opacity of the `div_block`...

Answer (score 0):

if you apply transparency to parent element then its child element will also get that effect. to avoid that you have to overlay the elements
now instead of applying opacity to body apply to some container and element which you want to overlay keep outside that container. 
I have not included javascript however it will do the same

also it's `document.body.style.opacity = "0.3";`

i have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfu14gd6/#) for you to understand

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>text</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .container{
            opacity: 0.3;
            background: yellow;
            height:400px;
            width:100%;
        }

        .over-lay{
            position:relative;
            bottom:250px;
            background: red;
            width:150px;
            height: 150px;
            margin:0 auto;

        }

        .container>div{
            background: purple;
            width:200px;
            margin:50 auto;

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        This is container
        <div>Another container</div>
    </div>
    <div class="over-lay">
        This is over-lay
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that everything within `body` will inherit any styles you set.

Why do you use `body` and not just a 100% height and width div?
If you use the div approach, you can separate the two elements and they won't inherit styles from each other.

Example HTML:

`<div id="container"></div>`

`<div id="div_block"></div>`

Example JS:

`document.getElementById("container").style="opacity:0.3";`
`document.getElementById("div_block").style="opacity:1";`

Comment: I want to popup the div tag.

Comment: What do you mean? Like a modal? Yeah, that'll still work.